# When I use Command + L I get a zsh terminal in Chrome. How can I focus on address bar in Chrome

Tags: shortcut

Some how my <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> shortcut is assigned to another thing. How can I make it default so that it will focus on address bar in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found that my iTerm > Preference > Hotkey was on.

After turning it off, it works now.

[image]